# Why does Java AQS queue traverse backwards

Tags: java, concurrency

Here's the reference from Doug Lea's paper:

> An AbstractQueuedSynchronizer queue node contains a next link to its
>   successor. But because there are no applicable techniques for
>   lock-free atomic insertion of double-linked list nodes using
>   compareAndSet, this link is not atomically set as part of insertion;
>   it is simply assigned: pred.next = node; after the insertion. This is
>   reflected in all usages. The next link is treated only as an optimized
>   path. If a node's successor does not appear to exist (or appears to be
>   cancelled) via its next field, it is always possible to start at the
>   tail of the list and traverse backwards using the pred field to
>   accurately check if there really is one.

And here's the Java 8 source code:

```
    private Node enq(final Node node) {
        for (;;) {
            Node t = tail;
            if (t == null) { // Must initialize
                if (compareAndSetHead(new Node()))
                    tail = head;
            } else {
                node.prev = t;
                if (compareAndSetTail(t, node)) {
                    t.next = node;
                    return t;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What if I change it to:

```
else {
    if (compareAndSetTail(t, node)) {
        t.next = node;
        node.pre = t;
        return t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, when the thread enters If statement and is interrupted by other threads, the head node traverses from the tail, and even cannot access the prev of the tail node.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void unparkSuccessor(Node node) {

    int ws = node.waitStatus;
    if (ws < 0)
        compareAndSetWaitStatus(node, ws, 0);

    Node s = node.next;
    if (s == null || s.waitStatus > 0) {
        s = null;

        // ✅ tail.prev = null

        for (Node t = tail; t != null && t != node; t = t.prev)
            if (t.waitStatus <= 0)
                s = t;
    }

    if (s != null)
        LockSupport.unpark(s.thread);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).